# Negation of "Diane rode her bicycle 100 miles on Sunday"

Tags: logic

Let P : Diane rode her bicycle 100 miles on Sunday.

The negation of P will be:

*It is not the case that* Diane rode her bicycle 100 miles on Sunday.

Can the negation of P be expressed in a simpler manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about: "Diane did not ride her bicycle 100 miles on Sunday."

Comment: I disagree. 

The way it is currently written, your answer negates the whole promise, ie. Diane did not ride her bicycle at all on Sunday.

If you could and wanted to make it 100% logically correct, you could write "Diane did not ride her bicycle exactly 100 miles on Sunday"

Comment: Excellent point, @algevristis.

Comment: Eh, it's not the poster's fault either.

A complete theory of types has not yet been written.

Answer (score 2):

Diane rode her bike less than or more than $100$ miles on Sunday.

Comment: (With riding a bike 0 miles corresponding to not riding a bike at all).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).